# Howto decode GE Logiq E9 Ultrasound Volume Images in Private DICOM Tags

Tags: dicom

I would like to access and display ultrasound images captured with a GE Logiq E9 and exported as a dicom directory.

The images sequence captured are normally used for Volume Navigation overlay. This is used for overlaying captured images (e.g. MR, CT or UV) over a live ultrasound session. But no available Framework or Viewer I tried was able to access the stored slices.

According to the [DICOM Conformance Declaration](http://www3.gehealthcare.de/~/media/documents/us-global/products/interoperability/dicom/ultrasound/gehc-dicom-conformance_logiqe9_2325843-100_rev9-02.pdf)

The sequences are saved in this private Tag:

```
GEMS_Ultrasound_MovieGroup_001
```

Can anybody shine some light on the format and decoding ?
Thanks

Comment: Are these 3D or 2D images? In which case you can probably look into the private group of data held in 7fe1, 1001. A tool like dicompyler can help look into the sequence for you to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The information in these tags is saved in a GE proprietary format, that is meant to be decoded by GE Healthcare software only. I doubt, that GE Healthcare has released or plans to release any information regarding these private tags.